# Active Directory: how to discover failed logins?

Tags: active-directory, login

I'm in a medium size enterprise environment using Active Directory for authentication etc. Considering if we should activate an account lockout policy for failed login attempts I need to gather statistics on the current number of such events.

I've read [MS Account Lockout Best Practices](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6218) but still, I'm nowhere near understanding how to do this. The document focuses on discovering the reasons for account lockout rather than getting a clear picture from the event logs.

So, my question is this: **where** should I look, **what** should I look for (specific event IDs, Failure Codes, anything else?) to find out the number of failed logins (the user tries over and over with the wrong password). Extra bonus if I can script the process.

Some additional info: The AD servers are Windows 2003 (with one extra running Windows 2008)

Please forgive my AD ignorance.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How many times do you think people are screwing up their passwords in the morning? You can activate the logging on the AD servers and gather the numbers from there, but practically in our environment we just set up a reasonable number and gauge from support calls. If people can't get their password in three to five times in a row, there is a problem with their use of the system, and setting it too high defeats the purpose (except from automated brute force.)

Answer (score 4):

Look (as in, apply a filter) in the Security event log on your domain controllers for EventCode 675, EventType 16. This equates to "Pre-authentication failed", which seems to be the precursor to EventCode 644, EventType 8 - "User Account Locked Out".